# TYPO3 upload multiple files in a frontend form

Tags: php, file, upload, typo3, extbase

I'm using the https://github.com/helhum/upload_example to create a form that allow file upload in frontend. It works fine with single file but I would need to upload multiple files.

So here is my form field :

```
<mr:form.upload property="files" id="publication-files-{contentUid}" class="file"
                        data="{loading-text: '{f:translate(key: \'uploading\', extensionName: extKey)}', max-file-size: maxFileSize}"
                        additionalAttributes="{autocomplete: 'off', accept: settings.allowedFiles, multiple: 'multiple'}"/>
```

Note that I've added the addition attribute "multiple".

When I send the form I always get 1 file in the `convertFrom` method of the `UploadedFileReferenceConverter` class, even if I've chosen 3 or 4...

Does someone already experimented that? If yes, please help :)

Thanks,

Jérémie

Comment: Here, you can find the change log for new support from here https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/pull/10/files. Here is the complete extension for multiple file upload https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/socioz

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I had to use the native "multiple" argument of form.upload ViewHelper like that :

```
<mr:form.upload property="files" multiple="multiple" id="publication-files-{contentUid}" class="file"
                        data="{loading-text: '{f:translate(key: \'uploading\', extensionName: extKey)}', max-file-size: maxFileSize}"
                        additionalAttributes="{autocomplete: 'off', accept: settings.allowedFiles}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.0` from property. This says: Use the domain model attribute "files" and declare the first array object.

so you must have:

```
<mr:form.upload property="files" id="publication-files-{contentUid}" class="file"
                        data="{loading-text: '{f:translate(key: \'uploading\', extensionName: extKey)}', max-file-size: maxFileSize}"
                        additionalAttributes="{autocomplete: 'off', accept: settings.allowedFiles, multiple: 'multiple'}"/>
```

Comment: If I do this I've got  `Exception while property mapping at property path "files.name": The identity property "my_file_name.png" is no UID.`.