# How to multiupload in Form of TYPO3 v9.5?

Tags: forms, file-upload, typo3, image-uploading, typo3-9.x

Since I'm using TYPO3 v9.5.3 and want to use the sysext "form" but cant manage it to accept & send multiuploads via mail.

What I have done so far:

Override standard .yaml file

```
plugin.tx_form {
    settings {
        yamlConfigurations {
            100 = fileadmin/Form/CustomFormSetup.yaml
        }
    }
}
```

created a new Template file for "ImageUpload.html" and added:

```
multiple="multiple"
```

so now it looks like that:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:formvh="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Form/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<formvh:renderRenderable renderable="{element}">
    <f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element}" contentAs="elementContent">
        <formvh:form.uploadedResource
            property="{element.identifier}"
            as="image"
            multiple="multiple"
            id="{element.uniqueIdentifier}"
            class="{element.properties.elementClassAttribute}"
            errorClass="{element.properties.elementErrorClassAttribute}"
            additionalAttributes="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'fluidAdditionalAttributes')}"
            accept="{element.properties.allowedMimeTypes}"
        >
            <f:if condition="{image}">
                <div id="{element.uniqueIdentifier}-preview">
                    <a href="{f:uri.image(image: image, maxWidth: element.properties.imageLinkMaxWidth)}" class="{element.properties.elementClassAttribute}">
                        <f:image image="{image}" maxWidth="{element.properties.imageMaxWidth}" maxHeight="{element.properties.imageMaxHeight}" alt="{formvh:translateElementProperty(element: element, property: 'altText')}" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </f:if>
        </formvh:form.uploadedResource>
    </f:render>
</formvh:renderRenderable>
</html>
```

Since now I also see the button changed to the plural version and I'm able now to select multiple files in the frontend.

What problem still presists:

When I select multiple files and send the form (then result gets send by mail) the Mail contains everything but uploads.
When switching back to single-upload-version everything works but just with one picture.

Is there someone who can help me with that?
What do I have to do to make form processing the images/uploads when I have multiple of them?

I also read this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172252/typo3-upload-multiple-files-in-a-frontend-form) but it did not solve my problem, as I want to solve this in the standard Form extension.

Comment: I have also the same problem but seems like nobody knows a solution in typo3 for such a simple problem...

Comment: But its a "Enterprise CMS" ;)

Comment: "EXT:Form" works only with one value for saving more one value, you have to write own finisher

Answer (score 4):

This thread is a bit old, but I was still facing the same problem in 2020 and decided to post a solution. If any experienced Typo3 developers will correct/add to my answer, this would be awesome.

1. Create a new form element for file uploads. In your extension, under Classes/Domain/Model add MultipleUpload.php:

```
<?php 

namespace YOUREXTKEY\Domain\Model;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\FormElements\GenericFormElement;

class MultipleUpload extends GenericFormElement
{
}
```

2. In your form setup yaml file, add a new element definition and a new finisher definition. My setup looks like:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formEditor:
            formEditorPartials:
              FormElement-MultipleUpload: 'Stage/SimpleTemplate'
          dynamicRequireJsModules:
              additionalViewModelModules:
                - 'TYPO3/CMS/YOUREXTKEY/Backend/FormEditor/MultipleUploadViewModel'
          formElementsDefinition:
            MultipleUpload:
              formEditor:                                
                label: 'MultipleUpload' 
                group: custom
                groupSorting: 1000
                iconIdentifier: 'form-text'
              implementationClassName: 'YOUREXTKEY\Domain\Model\MultipleUpload'
            Form:
              renderingOptions:
                properties:
                  elementClassAttribute: form
                templateRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:YOUREXTKEY/Resources/Private/Templates/Forms/'
                partialRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:YOUREXTKEY/Resources/Private/Partials/Forms/'
                layoutRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:YOUREXTKEY/Resources/Private/Layouts/Forms/'
          finishersDefinition:
            MultipleUploadsFinisher:
              implementationClassName: 'YOUREXTKEY\Finishers\MultipleUploadsFinisher'
```

3. Create a new finisher under Classes/Finishers/MultipleUploadsFinisher.php. I used the code from the standard Email Finisher and only edited the file attachment bit.

```
<?php 

namespace YOUREXTKEY\Finishers;

use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Model\FormElements\FileUpload;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Finishers\EmailFinisher;
use YOUREXTKEY\Domain\Model\MultipleUpload;
use TYPO3\CMS\Form\Service\TranslationService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage;

/**
 * Class MultipleUploadsFinisher
 */

class MultipleUploadsFinisher extends EmailFinisher {

  /**
   * Executes this finisher
   * @see AbstractFinisher::execute()
   */
  protected function executeInternal()
  {
      ... copied code from EmailFinisher

      if ($attachUploads) {
          foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if (!$element instanceof MultipleUpload) {
                continue;
            }
            $files = $formRuntime[$element->getIdentifier()];
            foreach ($files as $file) {
              if ($file) {
                $target_path = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('fileadmin/user_upload/') . basename($file['name']);
                if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {
                    $mail->attach(\Swift_Attachment::fromPath($target_path));
                }
                // unlink($target_path); (if you wish to delete uploads, uncomment this line)
              }
            }
          }
      }

      ... copied code from EmailFinisher
    }


}
```

4. Under Resources/Private/Partials/Forms add MultipleUpload.html with the following code:

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:formvh="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Form/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<formvh:renderRenderable renderable="{element}">
    <f:render partial="Field/Field" arguments="{element: element}" contentAs="elementContent">

        <div class="form-file-wrapper ">        
        <f:form.upload property="{element.identifier}" multiple="multiple" id="{element.uniqueIdentifier}" additionalAttributes="{multiple : '', accept : 'YOURMIMETYPES'}"/>

        <label for="{element.uniqueIdentifier}">
            YOUR LABEL TEXT HERE
        </label>
        </div>

    </f:render>
</formvh:renderRenderable>
</html>
```

5. Under Resources/Public/JavaScript/Backend/FormEditor/ add MultipleUploadViewModel.js with the following code:

```
// Resources/Public/JavaScript/Backend/FormEditor/MultipleUploadViewModel.js

    define([
        'jquery',
        'TYPO3/CMS/Form/Backend/FormEditor/Helper'
    ], function ($, Helper) {
        'use strict';

        return (function ($, Helper) {

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @var object
             */
            var _formEditorApp = null;

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return object
             */
            function getFormEditorApp() {
                return _formEditorApp;
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return object
             */
            function getPublisherSubscriber() {
                return getFormEditorApp().getPublisherSubscriber();
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return object
             */
            function getUtility() {
                return getFormEditorApp().getUtility();
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @param object
             * @return object
             */
            function getHelper() {
                return Helper;
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return object
             */
            function getCurrentlySelectedFormElement() {
                return getFormEditorApp().getCurrentlySelectedFormElement();
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @param mixed test
             * @param string message
             * @param int messageCode
             * @return void
             */
            function assert(test, message, messageCode) {
                return getFormEditorApp().assert(test, message, messageCode);
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return void
             * @throws 1491643380
             */
            function _helperSetup() {
                assert('function' === $.type(Helper.bootstrap),
                    'The view model helper does not implement the method "bootstrap"',
                    1491643380
                );
                Helper.bootstrap(getFormEditorApp());
            };

            /**
             * @private
             *
             * @return void
             */
            function _subscribeEvents() {
                /**
                 * @private
                 *
                 * @param string
                 * @param array
                 *              args[0] = formElement
                 *              args[1] = template
                 * @return void
                 */
                getPublisherSubscriber().subscribe('view/stage/abstract/render/template/perform', function (topic, args) {
                    if (args[0].get('type') === 'MultipleUpload') {
                        getFormEditorApp().getViewModel().getStage().renderSimpleTemplateWithValidators(args[0], args[1]);
                    }
                });
            };

            /**
             * @public
             *
             * @param object formEditorApp
             * @return void
             */
            function bootstrap(formEditorApp) {
                _formEditorApp = formEditorApp;
                _helperSetup();
                _subscribeEvents();
            };

            /**
             * Publish the public methods.
             * Implements the "Revealing Module Pattern".
             */
            return {
                bootstrap: bootstrap
            };
        })($, Helper);
    });
```

6. In your form.yaml file add the new finisher:

```
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'YOUR EMAIL SUBJECT'
      recipientAddress: YOUR EMAIL RECIPIENT
      recipientName: ''
      senderAddress: YOUR EMAIL SENDER
      senderName: YOUR EMAIL SENDER NAME
      replyToAddress: ''
      carbonCopyAddress: ''
      blindCarbonCopyAddress: ''
      format: html
      attachUploads: true
      translation:
        language: ''
      templatePathAndFilename: 'EXT:YOUREXTKEY/Resources/Private/Templates/Forms/Email/Html.html'
    identifier: MultipleUploadsFinisher
```

and also your element:

```
      
          -
            properties:
              elementClassAttribute: 'col col-12 mt-3'
              allowedMimeTypes:
                - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                - application/pdf
                - image/jpeg
                - image/png
                - text/plain
              elementDescription: ''
            type: MultipleUpload
            identifier: fileupload-1
            label: Files
```

Comment: Looks very good at first sight. I need exactly this in a current project, so I will try this tomorrow ;) Thanks ahead

Answer (score -2):

Adding the 'multiple' attribute will enable the file selector to select multiple files. But you will need to extend the viewhelper, 'formvh:form.uploadedResource' to handle these multiple files.

Even you can add your own viewhelper to implement what you wanted to do with the uploaded files.

Thanks.

[How to build a custom viewhelper](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html)